# What is this 某 doing after the names?

Tags: meaning

What is this 某 after the names? Could it be some kind of rank in the Air Force? Listening to the mp3, it sounds like 'mao' not 'mou' to my ear.

陈某和刘某都曾在空军部队。

Comment: 某某: so-and-so; 陈某: Chen so-and-so

Comment: Hi, I downloaded Pleco as you recommended. There's a lot of stuff to buy! I can't afford all of them! I like it, but the second word I entered came up as 2 characters, not a word: 停发，which was not the intended meaning.

Comment: If you had downloaded (even the free adsotrans dictionary!) some add-ons you would have found the word you're looking for. guifan: 停止发放 ads: to cease issuing GR: cesser de payer; suspendre le paiement.

Comment: I think 'a certain Chen', 'a certain Liu' would be better. It works not just with people's names, but with time phrases as well: '某年某月某日'

Comment: @Pedroski I don't have the paid add-ons either, only the CEDICT, Pleco dictionaries and the Unicode data, but it's still quite good, this 某 is actually included in the free dictionaries.

Comment: 停发 is included in the free ones aswell, but adsotrans is not the best

Answer (score 7):

It indicates that the given name is unknown or intentionally hidden. 'A certain Chen/Liu', 'a Mr. Chen/Liu', 'a Ms. Chen/Liu', etc.

In the case of women 氏 can be used, or was used historically, when only her maiden family name was recorded, e.g. Mao Zedong's paternal grandmother is quoted in Wikipedia as 罗氏, which simply means 'née Luo'.

Comment: I agree. Just to clarify, this usage of 氏 is for referring to the (possibly multiple) wives or concubines of a man; while 某 as used in the example sentence has no indication of gender to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes! This usage of 氏 is frequent in 射雕英雄傳 with examples like ：郭嘯天的渾家李氏⋯

Answer (score 2):

It is not rank related. Family name is Chen and Liu, Mou is just kind of omission.